Movie with plot similar to Final Destination
So the reason why I want to know this movie's name is because there's a drama coming out with a similar plot & I'm trying to remember where I've watched something so similar before. I'm not 100% sure but it may be a LMN movie or a regular murder/mystery.
I don't remember the actors or plot in details, but it was In English & the main characters were white. The setting was of present day (which will be the time it came out between 2009-10-11) it's action/thriller/mystery.
From what I could remember The plot goes like this:
– A woman can see accidents that takes place in the future through her dreams. She gets scared at first and tries to help those people but then A prosecutor got involved in the cases. He didn't believe her at first but then he saw for himself & started to believe her then he struggles to stop those dreams from becoming real. As in he help her whenever she gets a vision, they try to reach those people before the accident happens, however they weren't able to help every single person. Also the two got close to each other...

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give?Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

Could be The Eye 2008

The violinist Sydney Wells has been blind since she was five years old due to an accident. She submits to a surgery of cornea transplantation to recover her vision, and while recovering from the operation, she realizes that she's having strange visions. With the support of Dr. Paul Faulkner, Sidney finds who the donor of her eyes and begins a journey to find out the truth behind her visions.





This looks like it... It's been so long lol, I'll definitely have to check it out. Thank you so much!

No problem, happy to help.
